# Regex check if first subfolder ist "print"

Tags: regex, google-analytics

In Google Analytics i have to analyze all sizes which have the first sublfolder "print". Some examples are:

http://www.example.com/print/digitalprint and 
http://www.example.com/print/canvasprint

And so on, but the page rint itself should also be selected:
http://www.example.com/print.

Not inside the selection should be pages like http://www.example.com/web/printsolutions and so on.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Did you try `^/print(/.*)?$`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Analytics, the string passed to the regex is the path part after the host, so, all you need is to make sure the string starts with `/print` and then only matches the end of string or `/` and anything up to the end of string.

```
^/print(/.*)?$
```

This will match the `/print/digitalprint`, `/print/canvasprint`, and `/print` (and `/print/`, too), but won't match `/web/printsolutions`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p3rMvK/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `/print`  - a literal char sequence `/print`
- `(/.*)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `/` - a slash
  - `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string

Since `/` is not used as a regex delimiter, there is no point escaping it in a GA regex pattern.